# I can't find Modifier.pullRefresh in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, pull-to-refresh

I have tried many times to add pull refresh, but it does not exist for me, and swip refresh has been deprecated, so I cannot use it properly. How can I, or what things should I put in gradle in order to be able to use pull refresh?

After watching several clips and reading some articles, what became apparent to me is that pull refresh is the latest method launched, but no matter what I do, I cannot find this feature.

Comment: make sure you have at least     implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material' in the build file